# Detect mobile browser and redirect

Tags: c#, redirect, mobile

I want to use my .cs codebehind, either Page_PreInit or Page_Load to detect mobile browser and to redirect. I ran across this:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) 
    { 
        { 
          Response.Redirect("~/default_mobile.aspx"); 
        }

    } 
}
```

It doesn't appear to work. Can someone suggest a correction? Also, do you know of an example of NOT redirecting, but merely replacing an element on the .aspx page with another (i.e; replacing a Silverlight movie with a still image for an iOS device.)

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

[This MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice.aspx) explains how to use `.IsMobileDevice` in the context of a `Page_Load`. It should be trivial to adapt it to your needs.

Check also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224/mobile-device-is-detected-as-non-mobile-device)

And the [51Degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com), a class library that detects mobile devices and browsers, enhancing the information available to .NET.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this...I read it and tried the test on a page. It loads, it reads the code, but it displays "Browser is NOT a mobile device" for everything, including iPad and iPhone. Do I need to add assembly references to the top of the C# codebehind page?

Comment: Thanks again...I'm not clear on one thing--for my above code to work ((Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) -- do I NEED to have a class library like 51Degrees installed?

Comment: Is not a NEED, but 51Degrees [they claim] solves some problems such  as new mobile browsers not being detected, etc.

Comment: @user1628753, `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` is built-in to C#, whereas 51Degrees is a wholly separate Nuget package. They are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Add A global application class in the project and write the code in `Session_Start`

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
            {
                string path = httpRequest.Url.PathAndQuery;
               bool isOnMobilePage = path.StartsWith("/Mobile/",
                                                      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                if (!isOnMobilePage)
                {
                    string redirectTo = "~/Mobile/";

                    // Could also add special logic to redirect from certain 
                    // recognised pages to the mobile equivalents of those 
                    // pages (where they exist). For example,
                    // if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is UserRegistration)
                    //     redirectTo = "~/Mobile/RegistrationMobile.aspx";

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
                }
            }   
        }
```